# Why I am getting this Program 'flutter.bat' failed to run: The system cannot find the file specifiedAt line:1 char:1

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code, android-studio-3.0, hybrid

[image]

I am trying to create a flutter application in Visual Studio code which raising the above error.

[image]

Comment: Please read this article about **How to ask a question** carefully and improve your question accordingly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

Sound to me like you have not installed flutter SDK properly or VS code is having problems finding the SDk path. it can be any of those things.

Comment: I am able to run Flutter commands in the Flutter Console.so, I think flutter SDK is installed properly

Answer (score 0):

it seems you have not accepted all android licenses. try reinstalling android SDK and make sure to accept all android licenses.
then run

```
flutter doctor
```

and see if it passes all checks

Answer (score 0):

Since you have installed Flutter for the first time, you need to accept Android License to start building with Flutter.

To accept the license,

1. Open the terminal
2. Type `flutter doctor --android-licenses`
3. Press `y` to accept every license.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you installed git in correctly uninstall git and than install correctly. when you installing it select the options (use git and optional unix tools from the windows command prompt)

Answer (score -1):

This may be because your cmd.exe file located in system32 has been corrupted or lost. Try to get the cmd.exe file from another system and paste it into the desired location then execute if there is a flutter in your system or not.
This has solved the problem in my case.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).